# Javascript - Why does measuring time becomes inaccurate in a iterating function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, event-loop

Consider this piece of code

```
// Initialise the variables to check when the code started
let total_time = performance.now();
let recursions = 0;
function test() {
    recursions++;
    if (recursions === 60) {
        // Check how long it took to do 60 recursions
        console.log(`${performance.now() - total_time}ms`);
    }
// Timeout to call it 17ms later
setTimeout(() => test(), 17);
}
test();
```

This is meant to show when 60 recursions have happened to ensure that certain parts of my code are fired off correctly (without needing setTimeout as it's blocking) and I get between 1200 - 1600ms for no reason. I used a modified version that measured how long it took and it gave 0ms (for no reason). Anyone know why? And will the same happen in node.js?

*Code used to measure how long it took to do one recursion*

```
let start_time = performance.now();
let total_time = performance.now();
let measure = 0;
function test() {
    start_time = performance.now();
    measure++;
    if (measure === 60) {
        console.log(`${performance.now() - total_time}ms`);
    }
    console.log(`Taken ${performance.now() - start_time}`);
}
test();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supposed to be very accurate as you might expect since the timeout can fire an event later when the page is busy with other tasks.

`setTimeout` is implemented in a way it's meant to execute after a **minimum** given delay, and once the browser's thread is free to execute it. so, for an example, if you specify a value of 0 for the delay parameter and you think it will execute "immediately", it won't. it will, more accurately, run in the next event cycle (which is part of the event loop - concurrency model which is responsible for executing the code).

So for conclusion, you can't use `setTimeout` if you expect a consistent, reliable
and accurate timing in scale of millisecond.

Please read reason for delays longer then specified - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

More about the JS event loop - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Comment: Will the delays occur in node.js?

Comment: setTimeout is not part of the JS, it's a part of the platform (browser/node), hence, it will occur in both platforms.

Comment: o... okay, that sounds very fun to deal with